# Sklearn Decision Tree Classifier - Animal Guessing game

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to make an Animal Guessing game with sklearn's Decision tree classifier. In this, with the users input, it will say whether the animal is a spider or a fish. When I enter the number of legs and where it stays, it says animal is a fish and vice versa. This is the code, any ideas?

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
features=[[6,0],
      [6,0],                #0 is spider and 1 is fish
      [0,1],                #6 = 4 legs and 8=stays in land ( this is a spider)
      [0,1]]               #4=no legs and 7 is stays in water (this is a fish)
     

outcomes=[1,1,0,0]

clf.fit(features, outcomes)

legs=int(input("Enter the number of legs your animal has: "))
land_water=input("Enter whether you animal stays in land or water: ")
if land_water=="land":
   land_water=0
else:
   land_water=1

sa=clf.predict([[legs, land_water]])

if sa==[0]:
    print("Animal is a spider")
else:
    print('Animal is a fish')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inverted the `outcomes`, like this works for me:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
features=[[6,0],
      [6,0],                #0 is spider and 1 is fish
      [0,1],                #6 = 4 legs and 8=stays in land ( this is a spider)
      [0,1]]               #4=no legs and 7 is stays in water (this is a fish)
     

outcomes=["spider","spider","fish","fish"]

clf.fit(features, outcomes)

legs=int(input("Enter the number of legs your animal has: "))
land_water=input("Enter whether you animal stays in land or water: ")
if land_water=="land":
   land_water=0
else:
   land_water=1

sa=clf.predict([[legs, land_water]])
print(sa)
if sa[0] == "spider":
    print("Animal is a spider")
else:
    print('Animal is a fish')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, friend, but, can u tell me, what is: clf.fit(pd.DataFrame(features), outcomes) ? I never heard of this "pd.DataFrame"..

Comment: I removed that, it was a mistake sorry! Please up vote or accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Yes, I you remove the "pd.DataFrame", it will still work.

Comment: But, whoever replied, I voted that his answer was useful. Thanks